# Junit test class with multiple @Test methods

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have a Junit test class with multiple @Test methods in it that I need to run in order.  If there is an exception thrown in a method I would like to stop entire test case and error out, but all of the rest of the test methods running.

```
public class{

@Test{
 //Test1 method`enter code here`
}

@Test{
 //Test2 method
}

@Test{
 //Test3 method
}

}
```

If Test1 method fails then don't run other Tests

Note: All are independent tests

Answer (score 12):

Unit tests should be designed to run independently of one another. The order of execution cannot be guaranteed. You should redesign your test class so that the order is not important.

Without further information it's hard to advise you specifically. But it may help to have an `@before` method, which checks for some precondition before running each test. If you included an [`Assume.assumeTrue(...)`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html#assumeTrue%28boolean%29) method call, then your test could be skipped if the condition fails?

Answer (score 11):

As discribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13540131/1515052), JUnit 4.11 supports the ordered execution with the Annotation `@FixMethodOrder`, but the others are right, all tests should be independent of each other.

At the end of a test you can set a global success flag. This flag will be tested at the begining of each test. If the flag is not set by the end of one test(because it fails before finishing) all other tests will fail too.
Example:

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class ConsecutiveFail{
  private boolean success = true;

  @Test
  public void test1{
    //fist two statements in all tests
    assertTrue("other test failed first", success);
    success = false;
    //do your test
    //...

    //last statement
    success = true;
  }

  @Test
  public void test2{
    //fist two statements in all tests
    assertTrue("other test failed first", success);
    success = false;
    //do your test
    //...

    //last statement
    success = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to achieve what you are looking with intellij idea IDE, I am using community edition.

Go to Edit Configuration in the class where test methods available.( Run --> Edit Configurations)

Select Test kind as "**Class**"
as in the below Image.

[image]

When you run the Class Test it will execute all `@Test` Annotated methods inside the class as in below Picture.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you need the consequence to be kept and failing a test not to fail the whole set, put all such tests in one and test by assume.

Answer (score 1):

Here's example for TESTNG how to specify test running order:

```
@Test(priority = 1)
public void test1(){}

@Test(priority = 2)
public void test2(){}

@Test(priority = 3)
public void test3(){}
```